# Store and fetch customObject array in sessionStorage in angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular, object, typescript

I am storing PublicationdtoService[] custom object array in a session storage

```
_publicationList: PublicationdtoService[] = [];
sessionStorage.setItem('sessionPublicationList',JSON.stringify(this._publicationList));
```

and fetching it back from the object

```
this._publicationList =<PublicationdtoService[]> (JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('sessionPublicationList')));
Console.log(this._publicationList);
```

But i am getting the response in Object[] form and not PublicationdtoService[] form. What do I do?

response in console is 
[image]

But what I am expecting is: [image]

Please Help

Comment: loop inside the object and get the PublicationdtoService

Comment: Can `PublicationdtoService` be an interface instead? If no then split `PublicationdtoService` into an interface representing the data it holds, and move functions and any business to a service. Then your new interface will represent the data which is serialized/seserialized to/from session storage.

Comment: at present PublicationdtoService is a class in publicationdto.service.ts file.
@Injectable()
export class PublicationdtoService {
  constructor() {
  }
}

Will making it interface solve the issue?